# Select all checkbox only works some of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes, along with a hidden select all button inside the form. I use jQuery to listen for a button click outside the form, and then "click" the hidden button element to select all. Sometimes the page loads up and I click the button and it works perfectly. You can click it multiple times and they all check and uncheck as intended. The form submits perfectly.

Other times, however, the page will load up and I click the button and nothing happens. They don't check no matter how many times I click. I've found this happens a lot if the page sits for more than maybe 10 seconds without me doing anything. But it also can happen on page load. I can't understand why. Is there an error in my code somewhere that I'm just not seeing?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
                $('label.choice').toggleClass("choice-text-color");
            });
        } else {
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
                $('label.choice').toggleClass("choice-text-color");
            });
        }
     });

    $("#selectAll").click(function() {
            $('#select-all').click()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="selectAll" class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0"
                type="button" name="selectAll">Select All</button>


<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1" class="choice">ABC</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2"><label for="2" class="choice">DEF</label>
  (....etc.....)

<input type="checkbox" id="select-all" style="display: none;">
            <input type="submit" style="display: none;">

        </form>
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why the hidden checkbox? If the "Select All" button is clicked why bother clicking another hidden item that then selects all, just select all. Instead of looping through all the checkboxes to see if they are checked, just query for the checked or unchecked ones and apply the appropriate classes.

Comment: The select all button you physically click is outside the form. That's why there is a hidden checkbox for select all that is tied to the button outside. As I said in my explanation, this code works perfectly some of the time. What I'm wondering is why it doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: My first guess would be that it's related to `$(':checkbox').each...`. This I think, will include the `select-all` checkbox. Maybe that's creating unexpectedness...? Remove `display: none` and see if it's doing what you think.

Comment: Whether the button is inside or outside the `form` makes no difference in terms of the functionality you are working with here. Having one button tied to the functionality of another is of no real use or need here. So, again, I ask, what are you trying to do here, just have a "Select All" button? If we make your code cleaner and get to the point, you're issue will go away.

Comment: I'd like the user to be able to click the button labeled "#selectAll" that is outside the form (for display purposes) and have all of the checkboxes checked. The only way it will work for me so far is to tie that button to the hidden checkbox labeled "#select-all", and then have jquery run the loop. It works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Please see my answer below. The HTML and JavaScript/JQuery is much more simple and will work every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your issue is due to the extraneous markup you've added to facilitate the select all functionality and the JavaScript/JQuery tied to it.

All you need is a single button (it doesn't matter whether it's part of the form or not) to trigger the select/deselect operations. Also, since the button will not be transmitting any data as part of the form the `name` attribute should not be used.

Also, if you don't want users to see the form's submit button, then simply don't add one to the form. You can then programmatically submit the form with `$(form).submit()`.

```js
// Passing a function into JQuery is the same as document.ready
$(function(){
  // JQuery recommends the use of "on" to bind events
  $('#selectAll').on("click", function(event) {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
       this.checked = true; 
    });
    $('label.choice').addClass("choice-text-color"); // Update the class use
  });
});
```

```css
.choice-text-color {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="selectAll" class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Select All</button>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1" class="choice">ABC</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2"><label for="2" class="choice">DEF</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working much better. I think the main cause of my confusion was that I also have the submit button for the form located outside of the form and that, I believe, has to be tied to a hidden submit inside the form in order to function. At least, it was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Again, you don't need hidden elements inside of the `form` that tie to elements outside of the form. You can have your submit button anywhere you'd like. If you put it outside of the form, then just add the `form` attribute to it to "connect" it to the `form` as in: `<button type="submit" form="my-form">Submit</button>`, where `my-form` is the `id` (not the `name` of the `form`). But really, why are you concerned with putting elements outside of the `form` in the first place? Just put everything inside the `form` element. Any element can be placed within a `form` element, not just form fields.

Comment: I'll give that a try. It's mainly because I have a 2 column form and I just couldn't get the submit button to style correctly when it was inside the same element as one of the form columns. I found the jquery solution on Stack Overflow and it worked so I just went with it.

Comment: I don't know what original code you worked from, but you should understand that a `form` has no visual effect on a page. You could wrap everything in the `body` in a `form` and layout would not be affected. Whatever layout issue you had can be solved with CSS, not changing where the `form` is or whether something is in or outside of it.

Comment: Quick question: If some boxes are already checked when "select all" is clicked, it will uncheck them, while checking all the others. Do you have a quick suggestion for an If/Else statement that will ensure all boxes are selected/deselected?